# Existence of an entire function satisfying given conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Does a holomorphic function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ exists such that

\begin{align}
f(\partial \mathbb{E}) = \partial \mathbb{E} \quad \text{and} \quad f(z) \neq 0 \text{ for all }z\in\mathbb{C}
\end{align}
holds?

In this case: $\mathbb{E} := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$ and $\partial \mathbb{E} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}$.

I could not find a function that fulfils the conditions, so I thought about how to proof that there is no such function, which unfortunately I could not proof either.

Comment: What is $\mathbb E$?

Comment: What does the notation $\partial \mathbb{E}$ denote?

Comment: I added it to the question. I should have been a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\overline{\Bbb E}$ is compact and $f$ has no zeros, the maximum and the minimum of $|f|$ are both attained at $\partial\Bbb E$. So, $|f|$ is constant on $\overline{\Bbb E}$ and therefore $f$ is constant there. So, by the identity theorem, $f$ is constant. But then it's not true that $f(\partial\Bbb E)=\partial\Bbb E$.